# How do I remove an array item in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, collections

I have an array that I've created in TypeScript and it has a property that I use as a key. If I have that key, how can I remove an item from it?

Comment: Would be nice if they would add a .remove() method where you could simply pass in the value you want removed. I guess that would be too easy...

Answer (score 1084, accepted):

Same way as you would in JavaScript.

```
delete myArray[key];
```

Note that this sets the element to `undefined`.

Better to use the [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function:

```
const index = myArray.indexOf(key, 0);
if (index > -1) {
   myArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: You can add a type to that! `var index: number = myArray.indexOf(key, 0);`

Comment: @CorayThan Surely it would be implicitly typed as `indexOf` returns a `number`?

Comment: @Chris While it's obvious in this simple case, it can help you diagnose bugs faster if you define a type for every variable explicitly. You're using `index` in more than once place already and one of those places (`splice`) wants to see a number or you'll get an error. Currently the compiler can't prevent you making mistakes there.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers No, the compiler would create a different variable for all other index variables. So, when you declare your variables with var, let, const, it should be fine.

Comment: It doesn't set the element to `null`, it removes the property so it will read as `undefined` when accessed.

Comment: @blorkfish it's good to mention that if you have a list of objects, you can use `var index =  myArray.findIndex(x => x.prop==key.prop);`.

Comment: `splice` is a _function_ not a keyword.

Comment: Why `splice` should be better than `delete`? Thanks!

Comment: @Cirelli94 - you're responding to an older thread, but the answer to your question is that deleting an array element does not change its length or re-index the array. Because arrays are objects in JavaScript, `delete myArr[2]` literally deletes _the property_ `2` of `myArr`, which is also different than `myArr[2] = undefined`.

The moral of this story is to just use `splice` for this task because it is a safe way to get the desired effect without confusing side effects.

Comment: Splice is the right way to go. Filter does not work!

Comment: suppose i want to remove the all the array data where CategoryID equal to CatID. using spread operator we can clone by using filter method.

    var l=[...this.ListSubCat.filter(r => r.CategoryID != CatID)];
    this.ListSubCat=[]; // Set array as empty
    this.ListSubCat=  l;

Answer (score 386):

```
let foo_object; // Itemitem(object here) to remove
this.foo_objects = this.foo_objects.filter(obj => return obj !== foo_object);
```

Comment: This does not remove anything it simply filters. If the list actually needs to be modified this is not the way.

Comment: @user573434 yes, you are right, as the name indicate. But this is simple approach in case where you want to remove an object on successful delete api call etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on an array of objects without a unique key property. @user573434 the filter method returns a new array without the filtered object, so the resulting array does have the object removed.

Comment: i think in order to return it as an object you have to do this `this.foo_objects = this.foo_objects.filter(obj => obj !== foo_object)[0];`

Comment: This is the simplest solution so far, I like it! I kept wondering about any scenarios where you would want to change the actual array instead of creating a new copy of it, but couldn't think of any.

Comment: @mik-t I believe that underneath the covers, that's what the javascript engine does anyways because arrays are static sized.

Comment: This does not work!! I have used an array to keep track of routerLinks in my Angular App, and when I used the above code, it did not remove the link at all!! Splice works like a charm.

Comment: this doesn't modify the original array, it creates a new one

Comment: This works. just read the 2nd line carefully. he does a filter with obj != foo_object. and assigns it to the original variable, thus replacing the original array with one minus the filtered foo_object. used it with an array of objects with id   `deleteById(id: string) {
    this.data = this.data.filter(d => d.id !== id);
  }` Just one word of warning, if Ids are not unique you will remove all with the same `id`

Comment: @Markus. If there are multiple references to the original array, they will not be affected.

Comment: This does work, but if you are using the original array for a data store, it will not work as expected since you have to assign the newly return list back to your variable.

Comment: user573434 he is assigning object to same list as a new instance so it replace the required object in list

Comment: fwiw my IDE (at least) demanded I change `this.foo_objects = this.foo_objects.filter(obj => return obj !== foo_object);` to `this.foo_objects = this.foo_objects.filter((obj) => {return obj !== foo_object});`.

Answer (score 142):

With ES6 you can use this code :

```
removeDocument(doc){
   this.documents.forEach( (item, index) => {
     if(item === doc) this.documents.splice(index,1);
   });
}
```

Comment: Best solution to remove without changing array reference AND with possibility to implement specific equality algorythm

Comment: Best answer have found

Comment: Best answer if using ES6

Comment: You can also use: this.documents.forEach( (item, index, array) => {
     if(item === doc) array.splice(index,1);
   });  
Which can be a lot cleaner, especially when working with nested arrays.

Comment: This answer is better. but it only removes the first item matched.

Comment: @MashukurRahman question is about how to remove one item, not multiple ocurrences

Answer (score 46):

It is my solution for that:

```
onDelete(id: number) {
    this.service.delete(id).then(() => {
        let index = this.documents.findIndex(d => d.id === id); //find index in your array
        this.documents.splice(index, 1);//remove element from array
    });

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: What's nice about this solution is that it will work even when object equality fails to identify two objects as equal.

Answer (score 32):

let departments is an array. You want to remove an item from this array.

```
departments: string[] = [];

 removeDepartment(name: string): void {
    this.departments = this.departments.filter(item => item != name);
  }
```

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `splice` method on an array to remove the elements.

for example if you have an array with the name `arr` use the following:

```
arr.splice(2, 1);
```

so here the element with index 2 will be the starting point and the argument 2 will determine how many elements to be deleted.

If you want to delete the last element of the array named `arr` then do this:

```
arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1);
```

This will return arr with the last element deleted.

Example:

```
var arr = ["orange", "mango", "banana", "sugar", "tea"];
arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1)
console.log(arr); // return ["orange", "mango", "banana", "sugar"]
```

Comment: Just FYI, the splice method modifies the array (so in this case removes the last item) and returns the removed item(s), not the array itself.

Comment: It should actually be arr.splice(arr.length-1,1) to remove the last element.

Comment: In order to delete the last element of an array, I'd use Array's `pop` method instead of `splice`.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a simple one liner for removing an object by property from an array of objects.

```
delete this.items[this.items.findIndex(item => item.item_id == item_id)];
```

or

```
this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.item_id !== item.item_id);
```

Comment: The problem with first solution is that delete removes element, but array size remains the same as before deteling. In second solution we will have a new object, so if we have spme dependency then we are losing it. Splice (which is in the top answer) does not have this effect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think in my use case I had not discovered that yet. Well observed :)

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me.

Your array:

```
DummyArray: any = [
    { "id": 1, "name": 'A' },
    { "id": 2, "name": 'B' },
    { "id": 3, "name": 'C' },
    { "id": 4, "name": 'D' }
]
```

Function:

```
remove() {
    this.DummyArray = this.DummyArray.filter(item => item !== item);
}
```

Note: This function deletes all the objects form your array. If you want to delete a specific object from array then use this method:

```
remove(id) {
    this.DummyArray = this.DummyArray.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this, if you need to remove a given object from an array and you want to be sure of the following:

- the list is not reinitialized
- the array length is properly updated

```
    const objWithIdToRemove;
    const objIndex = this.objectsArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id === objWithIdToRemove);
    if (objIndex > -1) {
      this.objectsArray.splice(objIndex, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share why you used const for every variable?

Comment: @shivamsrivastava I like the code to be immutable where is possible; because of that I was using `const` instead of `let`.

Answer (score 13):

Multiple options in Typescript/Javascript to remove an element from Array.
Splice is the best option as

1. It removes inline without creating a new object
2. It properly updates the length of the array (wont leave blank null element)

Below is an example of removing an object based on some field in a object array using Splice function

```js
const persons = [
 {
   firstName :'John',
   lastName :'Michel'
  },
  {
   firstName :'William',
   lastName :'Scott'
  },  
  {
   firstName :'Amanda',
   lastName :'Tailor'
  }
]

console.log('Before Deleting :'+JSON.stringify(persons));
console.log('Deleting William:');
persons.splice(persons.findIndex(item => item.firstName === 'William'),1);
console.log('After Deleting William'+JSON.stringify(persons));
```

Comment: I think you have misused the word 'mutate' here because splice definitely mutates the original object

Answer (score 7):

```
let a: number[] = [];

a.push(1);
a.push(2);
a.push(3);

let index: number = a.findIndex(a => a === 1);

if (index != -1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 6):

**Answer using TypeScript spread operator (...)**

```
// Your key
const key = 'two';

// Your array
const arr = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
];

// Get either the index or -1
const index = arr.indexOf(key); // returns 0


// Despite a real index, or -1, use spread operator and Array.prototype.slice()    
const newArray = (index > -1) ? [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...arr.slice(index + 1)
] : arr;
```

Answer (score 6):

One more solution using Typescript:

```
let updatedArray = [];
for (let el of this.oldArray) {
    if (el !== elementToRemove) {
        updated.push(el);
    }
}
this.oldArray = updated;
```

Comment: While this does resolve the problem asked, it is expensive to execute because of the creation of a new array and looping over the original. Doing this kind of operation on a huge array could produce undesirable side effects like, harder on mobile batteries, long waiting, jank, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
function myFunction(ID){ 
let index = this.myArray.findIndex(d => d.ID === ID); //find index in your array
        console.log('index==',index);
        if (index > -1) {
          console.log('remaving at',index);
          this.myArray.splice(index, 1);//remove element from array
        }
}
```

**Note**: Your array must have a property called ID... otherwise it will return -1 which means not found

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add extension method for an array.

```
interface Array<T> {
      remove(element: T): Array<T>;
    }

    Array.prototype.remove = function (element) {
      const index = this.indexOf(element, 0);
      if (index > -1) {
        return this.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Abdus Salam Azad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript/55370276#55370276) , but passing array as parameter
from //https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/

```
function arrayRemove(arr:[], value:any) { 
    
    return arr.filter(function(ele){ 
        return ele != value; 
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not "removing an item", this is "creating a new array without that item". Entirely different things.

Comment: @Clashsoft, true, but people often prefer immutable calls. If you want , you can re-assign result to the same variable myArr=arrayRemove(myArr, elemToRemove).

Answer (score 1):

```
_.pull(array,'a');
```

with a lib lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pull
complelte code:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
const allTagList = ['a','b','b']
_.pull(allTagList, b);
console.log(allTagList) // result: ['a']
```

PS: Lodash offer lots of operator, recommed to use it to simply your code.  https://lodash.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get index or position of list or array first, then use for loop to assign current array to a temp list, filter out unwanted item and store wanted item back to original array

```
removeItem(index) {
    var tempList = this.uploadFile;
    this.uploadFile = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < tempList.length; j++) {
      if (j != index)
        this.uploadFile.push(tempList[j]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can implement the logic using `filter` and `includes`

```js
const checkAlpha2Code = ['BD', 'NZ', 'IN']

let countryAlpha2Code = ['US', 'CA', 'BD', 'NZ', 'AF' , 'AR' , 'BR']


/**
 * Returns the modified array countryAlpha2Code 
 * after removing elements which matches with the checkAlpha2Code
 */
countryAlpha2Code = countryAlpha2Code.filter(alpha2code => {
    return !checkAlpha2Code.includes(alpha2code);
});
console.log(countryAlpha2Code)
// Output: [ 'US', 'CA', 'AF', 'AR', 'BR' ]


// Resetting the values again
countryAlpha2Code = ['US', 'CA', 'BD', 'NZ', 'AF' , 'AR' , 'BR']


/**
 * Returns the modified array countryAlpha2Code 
 * which only matches elements with the checkAlpha2Code
 */
countryAlpha2Code = countryAlpha2Code.filter(alpha2code => {
    return checkAlpha2Code.includes(alpha2code);
});

console.log(countryAlpha2Code)
// Output: [ 'BD', 'NZ' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many complaints that `remove` method is not in-built. Consider using `Set` instead of array - it has `add` and `delete` methods in-built.