# Remove objects from array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

how do i remove object from an array in typescript?

```
"revenues":[
{
        "drug_id":"20",
        "quantity":10
},
{
        "drug_id":"30",
        "quantity":1    
}]
```

so i want to remove the drug_id from all objects.
how do i achieve that?
Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: java or typescript?

Comment: no its type script and i want to remove drug_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove an array item in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use that :

```
this.revenues = this.revenues.map(r => ({quantity: r.quantity}));
```

For a more generic way of doing this :

```
removePropertiesFromRevenues(...props: string[]) {
  this.revenues = this.revenues.map(r => {
    const obj = {};
    for (let prop in r) { if (!props.includes(prop) { obj[prop] = r[prop]; } }
    return obj;
  });
}
```

Comment: this.revenues = this.revenues.map(r => ({quantity: r.quantity}));  will it remove the quantity field? thanks

Comment: No, it will remove the id, like you asked

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Array.prototype.map` like this:

```
revenues = this.revenues.map(r => ({quantity: r.quantity}));
```

The `Array.prototype.map` will take each item of your `revenues` array and you can transform it before returning it.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

So if you want for example double each quantity and add or rename some fields, you can do like below:

```
revenues = this.revenues.map(r => ({quantity: r.quantity, quantity2: r.quantity * 2}));
```

Comment: what this actually will do?would u explain that to me?thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Array.prototype.map` will transform your array to a new one depending on he given transformation rules returned by the callback. In this case, with the implicit return, our callback return a new object that holds only this field `{quantity: r.quantity}`

Comment: let's say i have  "revenues":[
{
        "drug_id":"20",
        "quantity":10,,  "price":10 
},
{
        "drug_id":"30",
        "quantity":1 ,  "price":10   
}]                                                                                                                    so i want to return only drug_id and quantity ,will urs option will do that?

Comment: So you need to write `revenues = revenues.map(item => { drug_id: item.drug_id, quantity : item.quantity })`. I will edit my answer to give you more explanation on how `map` works

Comment: You're welcome, so don't forget to upvote and mark the correct solution for your question!

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
revenues.forEach((object) => delete object.drug_id );
```