# How to remove index in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to delete per index, i have a parameter and remove button i tried to put my parameter inside my remove button but it wont work how to fix that?

```
deleteRowFiles(rowIndex: number){
  this.getListFileName();
  if(this.uploadAttachments.length > 1){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'You will not be able to recover this data!',
      icon: 'error',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel'
    }).then((result) => {
      if(result.value){
       
        this.uploadAttachments.removeAt(rowIndex);
        
        this.microSvc.deleteFile(this.iData.transactionType,this.uploadedFiles).pipe(
         return this.refreshPage();
        }) 
       
      }else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel){}
    })
   
  }
```

> HTML

```
<td (click)="deleteRowFiles(i)">
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
</td>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript) help you?

Comment: this answer helped me perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

There is no removeAt in javascript you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead

```
 this.uploadAttachments.splice(rowIndex,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always replace the array reference with a new array where the item to be removed has been filtered out

```
this.uploadAttachments = this.uploadAttachments.filter((_, i) => i !== rowIndex);
```