# TypeError: this.options.pull is not a function getting this error in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting, push, pull

> TypeError: this.options.pull is not a function getting this error in
> angular

I am having an array "options".In this array I am trying to change one element on every click..
oninit i am pushing one element in to this array and after clicking an option i need to pull out that last element and push other element in place of the last element.But getting error mentioned above.I am able to push but not able to pull out .Can anybody help me to resolve this.
i have already tried with delete and remove methods but getting the same error

```
 ngOnInit() {
   
this.arrayform();

x:any;
  arrayform()
  {
   
    
   this.x=this.saveCap[this.userIndex]
    console.log(this.x)
     this.options.push(this.x)
  
   console.log(this.options)
   console.log(this.x)
  }
  arrayDel(){
    console.log(this.options)
   console.log(typeof(this.options)) 
    console.log(this.x)
    this.options.pull(this.x)
  }
 checkoptions(){
    this.userIndex++
  //  this.options.remove(this.x)
  this.arrayDel();
    this.arrayform();
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Where is options declared?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove an array item in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292278/how-do-i-remove-an-array-item-in-typescript)

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm before ngOnit i have declared it  saveCont: any = [];
  options:any=[];
  newArr:any=[];
  saveCap:any=[];
  value: any;
  countryData:any;
  score=0;
  ngOnInit() {

Comment: @DonJuwe Probably not

Comment: change your any type to any[];

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Now getting error property "pull" does not exist on type any[]

Comment: Ah yeah, got confused myself, there is no pull for arrays in javascript.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm so how to remove any element from array?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?retiredLocale=de

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I used splice method and it's working